# How to delete old database

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the PostgreSQL app and I want to delete my old database for my old project. How do I do that? I've tried `drop database portfoliodb` but it's still there and I don't receive any feedback.

[image]

Comment: What did it say when you ran the drop command? And have you tried closing the PostgreSQL app and re-opening it?

Comment: It just enters into a new line. I did restart the app. Going to restart the computer now since I just noticed I can't even create a new db

Comment: Did the new line end with `-#` or `=#`?

Comment: @James it ends with `-#`

Comment: That means you forgot to add a semicolon on the end of your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, connect to `postgres` not to `portfoliodb`. You cannot drop the database that you (or anybody else) is connected to.
- Then, don't forget the semicolon after the SQL statement to complete it:

  ```
  DROP DATABASE portfoliodb;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add a semicolon on the end of your command.

You ran: `drop database portfoliodb`

But you should have run: `drop database portfoliodb;`